# How do you beat Talbot in Uncharted 3?

Tags: uncharted-3

I have already beat Uncharted 3 on Normal and I am trying to do it on Hard. I have gotten to the final boss fight with Talbot and nothing I do seems to work. I can only attack him at the very beginning of the fight. After about 30 seconds of fighting, every time I press square to attack him he puts me in the hold where he holds my arm behind my back and tries to stab me. I press circle as fast and as many times as possible but Nate never bites his arm. Talbot always just throws me out of the hold. This just happens over and over again for sometimes longer than 10 minutes or until I get frustrated and start over. I must be doing something wrong or there is a glitch in the game. Please help me out?

Comment: none of the answers to that question helped

Comment: You sure you're tapping the Circle button fast enough? See here: http://community.us.playstation.com/message/37138237. Sounds like the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

When he gets you in a hold, or on the ground, you need to press the circle faster than is humanly possible, for longer than a human can possibly do it. Well, not quite. If other people in the house get worried and ask "what's going on ..", you may be doing it fast enough.

In between holds, I gave up camera control and used the 1st three fingers of my right hand to more or less simultaneously mash the square, triangle and circle buttons, which seemed rather effective. This didn't have to be done as fast as the circle to break a hold, but it still had to be done rapidly. I did this initially for a couple of minutes and Talbot wasn't able to get one hit on me (on crushing even), but this turned out to be a Bad Thing; you need to let him get you into a hold at least once, b/c the story depends on it.

Both of these are very fatiguing, and if you don't get him right away, your button rep rate will go down, Talbot will start winning, and 20 minutes later you'll give up with incipient carpal tunnel syndrome.

Also, in my opinion, the fight with Talbot in the middle of the game (near the fountain) was equally as difficult, so if you can beat him there, you should be able to beat him at the end.